# How to handle lots of file downloads from my linux server

Tags: linux, file, download, hosting, server

I have a file 50MB file hosted in my deticated linux server, each day there is almost 50K users that download this file (2.5GB a day).

There are lots of crashes and users reports that sometimes even the file can't be downloaded since the server is overload.

I wonder if someone can help me how do I calculate which server/bandwidth/anything I need to handle that?

Is there any solution where I can host the file and pay per download?

Is there any setting or anything that I can improve or do on my server that will help to fix this issue?

My current server specification is:

- 2 x Intel Xeon E5 2620V2
- 2 x (6 x 2.10 GHz)
- 128 GB REG ECC
- 256GB SSD HD
- 1 IP Address
- 1 Gbit/s port Shared Bandwidth

I'll appreciate any help from you guys.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your hardware configuration should probably be fine. At least if the downloads are more or less evenly distributed over the day.

One of the most effective http servers for serving static content is nginx. Take a look at this guide: [Serving static content](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/).

If that doesn't help, you should consider [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which is probably the most popular file hosting solution with a reasonable price tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is how *not* to make the file available for download:

```
data = read_file(filename)
echo data
```

You want to be using [`sendfile(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) to have the kernel stream the file directly into the socket instead of doing it in userspace.

Each server has their own mechanism for invoking `sendfile(2)`; with httpd this is [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) and its associated response header (`X-SENDFILE`). You'll find that moving to this will allow you to not only handle your current userbase but also to add many more without worry.